# What is the optimal stopping point for an experiment when expecting unknown event

Tags: probability, optimization, stopping-times

Assume we notice that stock prices are rising and we can deduce we are in a bubble. Assume we start at $w(0)=0$ worth at time $t=0$ and the value grows linearly with time $(w(t)=t)$. We know that there will be a point where the prices will plummet and we lose everything if we haven't sold by that time $(w(t_f)=-1/2 t_f^2)$.

If the time till the burst of bubble is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$, so $t_f \sim exp[\lambda]$. Assume also that the parameter can be approximated with some accuracy, so we know what $\lambda$ is.

So the worth function would be something like:  $w(t) =
\begin{cases}
t,  & t<t_f \\
-1/2 t^2, & t=t_f  \\
0, & t>t_f
\end{cases}$

What would be the optimal time $t_s$ to sell all the money if all we know is that the fall will happen following exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$? Optimal would mean, I think, that $E(w(t))$ is maximized. I think we would have to compute integral $$\int_0^{t_s}\int_0^{\infty} \lambda e^{- \lambda t_f} w(t) \ dt_f \ dt$$ and find $t_s$ that maximises that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your value for $t = t_f$, but no matter, it won't contribute to the integral.  Your double integral is wrong, though.  The expected value should be
$$ E(w(t_s)) = t_s \int_{t_s}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\ dt = t_s e^{-\lambda t_s}$$
and the maximum of this is at $t_s = 1/\lambda$.